# How can I edit routes.rb in runtime dynamically from rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a situation that I needed to edit routes.rb from rails app progammatically. Need an idea how to do it. I am rails beginner.

Comment: Sure would be great to get some context here. If you're a beginner at Rails, you very well may just be missing something and really have no need to have your application modify `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: I guess you may have to define rails routes dynamically or something similar .. do correct ur question... its okkk to be beginner but you missed completely on what you wanted to do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change something in "routes.rb" you must restart app, so It is very bad idea. You can do with one controller/route. This controller can redirect to some other other controller or do something so you can use ONE ROUTE in routes.rb. You can write some your code here and We will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I just didnt need do that.

Comment: I need to dynamic add resources xxxx under routes.b, because I add model for user's table.

Comment: @parzival same what I wrote before. So your code allow users create some model? I'm just guessing, but you can create routing like this: /user/:id/:user_class/:user_class_id and write all routes what 'resources :xxxs' do for you. It's just alias. I think you can create new question and we will answer you better if you add more description about it.